# Show alertView in appDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, notificationcenter, control-center

I'm trying to add an `alertView` before the notification/control center is visible with 2 `buttons`. One `button` would be "ok" and the notification/control center should then open. The second `button` should be cancel, and the notification/control center should not be displayed.

I tried adding an `alertView` in `applicationWillResignActive` like so:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When the user tries opening notification/control center, it opens slightly, then closes and the `alertView` is shown. How can I make the `alertView` show without the notification/control center opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AlertView is showing because your app is about to resign active as Notification Center is showing, and you are launching it from the appDelegate method which handles this transition.

What is it you're trying to accomplish? It is not possible to have your app prevent the Notification Center from showing, or to open it programmatically from the AlertView.

You can check the iOS application states in table 2-3:

[iOS App Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html)

Comment: Is it possible to make it come after the alertview instead of before?

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can't affect the behavior of the system level panels (Notification Center and Control Center). Your app just gets notified whenever it loses active (for any reason).